# get NativeCommandError when running powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm looking some help. I have batch file on remote PC like this (Path on remote PC = C:\temp\silentsophos.bat) :

```
\\svr-sophos\SophosUpdate\CIDs\S000\SAVSCFXP\Setup.exe -mng yes -updp \\svr-sophos\SophosUpdate\CIDs\S000\SAVSCFXP -ouser <USERNAME> -opwd <PASSWD> -s -ni
```

and I tryin to execute that with powershell, which is the script is :

```
invoke-command -computername PC01 -scriptblock  {(&C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c C:\temp\silentsophos.bat)}
```

and the result i get is :

```
Access is denied.
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Access is denied.:String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
+ PSComputerName        : PC01
```

already tried with "2> $null", the error message is not showing up but on the remote PC seems nothing being executed or started.

Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: What are the round brackets supposed to do?

Comment: use the `-Credential` parameter on Invoke-Command ??

Comment: To add to @Theo's comment: It sounds like the batch file you're running remotely requires elevation (run as admin). If so, use `-Credential` with admin credentials. As an aside: You don't need `cmd /c` to invoke a batch file - just invoke it directly.